# Does accessing an int with a char * potentially have undefined behavior?

Tags: c, casting, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

The code below for testing endianness is expected to have implementation defined behavior:

```
int is_little_endian(void) {
    int x = 1;
    char *p = (char*)&x;
    return *p == 1;
}
```

But is it possible that it may have undefined behavior on purposely contrived architectures? For example could the first byte of the representation of an `int` with value `1` (or another well chosen value) be a trap value for the `char` type?

As noted in comments, the type `unsigned char` would not have this issue as it cannot have trap values, but this question specifically concerns the `char` type.

Comment: Could you use `unsigned char` which I believe is guaranteed to not have any trap values?

Comment: Note that `unsigned char` cannot have trap values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per C 2018 6.2.5 15, `char` behaves as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`. Suppose it is `signed char`. 6.2.6.2 2 discusses signed integer types, including `signed char`. At the end of this paragraph, it says:

> Which of these [*sign and magnitude*, *two’s complement*, or *ones’ complement*] applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones’ complement), is a trap representation or a normal value.

Thus, this paragraph allows `signed char` to have a trap representation. However, the paragraph in the standard that says accessing trap representations may have undefined behavior, 6.2.6.1 5, specifically excludes character types:

> Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is produced by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined. Such a representation is called a trap representation.

Thus, although `char` may have trap representations, there is no reason we should not be able to access it. There is then the question of what happens if we use the value in an expression? If a `char` has a trap representation, it does not represent a value. So attempting to compare it to 1 in `*p == 1` does not seem to have a defined behavior.

The specific value of 1 in an `int` will not result in a trap representation in `char` for any normal C implementation, as the 1 will be in the “rightmost” (lowest valued) bit of some byte of the `int`, and no normal C implementation puts the sign bit of a `char` in the bit in that position. However, the C standard apparently does not prohibit such an arrangement, so, theoretically, an `int` with value 1 might be encoded with bits 00000001 in one of its bytes, and those bits might be a trap representation for a `char`.

Comment: You nailed it! You also pointed in comments that neither `unsigned char` nor `signed char` can have padding bits, which restricts the possibility for trap values to the paragraph you quoted. This precision would belong in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the Standard would forbid an implementation in which `signed char` used sign-magnitude or ones'-complement format, and trapped on attempts to load the bit pattern that would represent "negative zero".  Nor does it require that such implementations must make `char` unsigned.  It would be possible to contrive an architecture upon which your code could have arbitrary behavior.  A few more important things to note, however:

1. There is no guarantee that the bits within a `char` are mapped in the same sequence as the ones in an `int`.  The code wouldn't launch into UB-land if the bits aren't mapped in order, but the result would not be very meaningful.
2. So far as I can tell, every non-contrived conforming C99 implementation has used two's-complement format; I consider it doubtful that any will ever do otherwise.
3. It would be silly for an implementation to make `char` be a type with fewer representable values than bit patterns.
4. One could contrive a conforming implementation that would do almost anything with almost any source text, provided that there exists some source text that it would process in the fashion defined by the Standard.

One could contrive a conforming sign-magnitude implementation where the integer value 1 would have a bit pattern that would encode signed char value "negative zero", and which would trap on an attempt to load that.  One could even contrive a conforming ones'-complement implementation that did so (have lots of padding bits on the "int" type, all of which get set when storing the value "1").  Given that one could contrive a conforming implementation that uses the One Program rule to justify doing anything it liked with the above source text regardless of what integer format it uses, however, I don't think the possibility of weird `char` type should really be a worry.

Note, btw, that the Standard makes no effort to forbid silly implementations; it might be improved by adding language mandating that `char` must either be a two's-complement type with no trap representations or an unsigned type, and either mandating the same for `signed char` or explicitly saying that is not required.  It might also be improved if it recognized a category of implementations which can't support types like `unsigned long long` [which would be a major stumbling block for a 36-bit ones'-complement systems, and may be the reason that no conforming C99 implementations exist for such platforms].

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Of this is no cause for worry, I am just looking for ways to simplify the Standard by identifying subtile constraints that would make non 2's complement representations non conformant.

Comment: @chqrlie: The problem with the Standard isn't that it's too complicated, nor that it's too simple, but rather that it fails to recognize that there are some features and guarantees which should be provided on the majority of implementations but not necessarily all, and there should be an easy way via which programs which aren't programmed to accommodate "quirky" implementations can refuse to run on them without ever having to rely upon "Undefined Behavior".

Comment: You focus on non 2's complement behavior, where negative zero could be trap value for `char`, but I do not see anything in the Standard that prevents `char` from having padding bits even on 2's complement architectures (except common sense)

Comment: @chqrlie: `char` cannot have padding bits because it has the same behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, and `signed char` cannot have padding bits as explicitly stated in 6.2.6.2 2, and `unsigned char` cannot have padding bits because all its bits are used for the value.

Comment: Character types are excluded from the rule about undefined behavior when trap representations are read, per C 2018 6.2.6.1 5: “Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined.…”

Comment: I wish I could accept both your and Eric's answer, but his is better documented with C Standard references.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Interesting observation, though I think the authors should have also specified that reading an object using an containing lvalue of struct or union type should have defined behavior even if the member holds a trap representaiton.

Comment: @supercat: C 2018 6.2.6.1 6 says “The value of a structure or union object is never a trap representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or union object may be a trap representation.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Indeed, but the text you cited says that if the bytes of an object hold a trap representation, accessing the object via anything other than a character type will invoke UB.  An access to a struct or union object is *also* an access to its member objects, and if one part of the Standard describes a behavior while another part characterizes an overlapping category of actions as invoking UB, the latter prevails.

Comment: @supercat: It is quite clear the intent of 6.2.6.1 6 is to tell us we can read and write a whole struct or union without ever having trap representations, regardless of what is in the members.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Twenty years ago, the intention of the Committee might have meant something.  Today, however, it is fashionable for compiler writers/maintainers to ignore it in pursuit of "optimization".

Comment: Yes, I hate it when computers ”go fast” and “use less energy.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Given a choice between a program that behaves usefully, versus a more "efficient" program that behaves uselessly, I'd personally prefer the former.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189988/discussion-between-eric-postpischil-and-supercat).

Comment: @supercat: That is not a given. Both are available.

Answer (score 1):

I found a quote from the Standard that proves that no object representation is a trap value for `unsigned char`:

6.2.6.2 Integer types

> 1 For unsigned integer types other than **unsigned char,** the bits of the object
>   representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need
>   not be any of the latter). If there are N value bits, each bit shall represent a different
>   power of 2 between 1 and 2N−1, so that objects of that type shall be capable of
>   representing values from 0 to 2N − 1 using a pure binary representation; this shall be
>   known as the value representation. The values of any padding bits are unspecified.53)

The previous says that an `unsigned char` cannot have any padding bits.

The following footnote says that padding bits are what can be used for trap representations.

> 53) Some combinations of padding bits might generate trap representations, for example, if one padding
>   bit is a parity bit. Regardless, no arithmetic operation on valid values can generate a trap
>   representation other than as part of an exceptional condition such as an overflow, and this cannot occur
>   with unsigned types. All other combinations of padding bits are alternative object representations of
>   the value specified by the value bits.

So I guess the answer is that `char` is not guaranteed to not have any trap values but `unsigned char` is.

Comment: Why are people voting this up? The question specifically asks about `char` and not `unsigned char`, yet the the bulk of this answer covers `unsigned char` and padding bits (which are not present in `char`) and only “guesses” in the last sentence that `char` is not guaranteed not to have any trap representations without supporting that guess.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The Standard does not guarantee that `char` cannot have padding bits. And in an implementation that have them there might very well be a trap value. No guessing. The answer offers `unsigned char` as an option.

Comment: Per 6.2.5 5, a `signed char` occupies the same amount of storage as a `char`. Per 6.2.5 15, `char` has the same range, representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`. Per 6.2.6.2 2, `signed char` shall not have any padding bits. Per 6.2.6.1, values stored in objects of type `unsigned char` are represented using pure binary. Footnote 49 makes it clear this phrase means `unsigned char` can represent all values from 0 to 2**CHAR_BIT-1, thus using all the bits. There are no padding bits.